# Google sheets not working for release apk flutter

Tags: android, flutter, google-sheets

I have an app that takes data from google sheets and also writes data to it. It works fine with debug apk but when I use release apk, neither can I write data to sheets nor read from it. Can anyone please tell me what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was working fine after I added these statements -:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: I think that wasn't the case,,, sometimes when you make a release version you need to first run `flutter clean` in your terminal, otherwise it just builds an older version of your app.